# Get the file hierarchy of a directory by the file path with Python

Tags: python, hierarchy, filepath

Here is my question. I used os.walk to get all the file paths under a specific directory and stored the path in a file like this

```
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-13/87009
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-19/91961
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-19/thumbs/_thumb_91961.png
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-11/86413
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-11/thumbs/_thumb_86412.png
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-11/thumbs/_thumb_86413.png
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-12/86614
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-16/90240
/indexes/attachment/CCTBAU/CCTBAU-17/90241
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-200/91345
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-200/96305
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-200/99169
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-201/91344
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-202/91346
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-197/88916
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-189/73799
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-38/60709
/indexes/attachment/ACD/ACD-198/88918
```

Now, I want to get the file hierarchy by reading all paths in the file, which means that I read the file and get all the paths, then I can know the file hierarchy is

```
index
  |--attachment
         |-----ACD
         |      |---ACD-200
         |      |---...
         |
         |-----CCTBAU
                |----CCTBAU-13
                |----...
```

Who can help out of this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I use os.listdir, and codes are as below:

```
  1 import os
  2
  3 def PrintDir(dir, depth, prefix = '    '):
  4     contents = os.listdir(dir)
  5     paths = filter(lambda x : os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir, x)), contents)
  6     files = [x for x in contents if x not in paths]
  7     if not paths and not files:
  8         return
  9
 10     print depth * prefix + '|----' + os.path.basename(dir) \
               if depth != 0 else os.path.basename(dir)
 11     for subdir in paths:
 12         PrintDir(os.path.join(dir, subdir), depth+1, prefix)
 13     for filename in files:
 14         print depth * prefix + '|----' + filename
 15
 16 PrintDir('~/testdir', 0)
```

You can also use os.walk to get what you want, as return value of os.walk is a tuple:
root, dirs, files.

test case is :

testdir/a/aa/aaa
testdir/b/bb/bbb
testdir/b/bb.txt

and aaa, bbb, bb.txt are files.

and output is:

```
testdir
    |----a
        |----aa
            |----aaa
    |----b
        |----bb
            |----bbb
        |----bb.txt
```

Comment: Actually, there is a shell tool named `tree`.